# Saving and reloading legend settings using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, legend

I know how to change settings of a legend individually by arcpy (like: Patch, Title, Items, Columns, Frame, Element Size & Position, etc.), but now I would like to use the exact legend settings another time and load them using ArcPy.

Is there a simple way to save/load these legend settings all together in/from a text file?

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like you know how to get at the elements you need, and they are all read/write. I've done something similar where I read properties from a raster and write them out to a XML configuration file that in turn gets read by another Python script and the raster parameters get fed into a 3D modeling package. `xml.etree.Elementree` and `xml.dom.minidom` are the key modules (at least for my version).

First, read your legend elements and get the values into variables, then write them out to XML. Below, `<..>_element` each represent a element that I write out, where `f` is a file named Config.xml:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import re

viesore_element = xml.etree.ElementTree.Element("VIESORE.Configuration")
comment = xml.etree.ElementTree.Comment("Auto-generated at " + str(write_time))
viesore_element.append(comment)
project_element = xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement(viesore_element, 
                                                       "ProjectDirectory")
project_element.text = proj_dir
scene_element = xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement(viesore_element, 
                                                     "Scene")
# Write some more values out

# Get rid of extra line returns in prettified XML
uglyXml = prettify(viesore_element)
text_re = re.compile('>\n\s+([^<>\s].*?)\n\s+</', re.DOTALL)    
prettyXml = text_re.sub('>\g<1></', uglyXml)

f = open(os.path.join(proj_dir, filename), "w")
f.write(prettyXml)
f.close()
```

This gives me a XML file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<VIESORE.Configuration>
  <!-- Auto-generated at 11/14/2011 12:54:01 -->
  <ProjectDirectory>D:\Projects\VIESORE\Code\viesore\Python</ProjectDirectory>
  <Scene>loader.vue</Scene>
  <RenderOutputQuality>High</RenderOutputQuality>
  <Terrain>
    <TerrainFile>raster.txt</TerrainFile>
    <TerrainWidth>1064</TerrainWidth>
    <TerrainHeight>1327</TerrainHeight>
    <TerrainMinElevation>351.042327881</TerrainMinElevation>
    <TerrainMaxElevation>538.774719238</TerrainMaxElevation>
    <TerrainCellResolution>9.36747778088</TerrainCellResolution>
  </Terrain>
  <Sun>
    <SunPitch>30</SunPitch>
    <SunAzimuth>220</SunAzimuth>
  </Sun>
</VIESORE.Configuration>
```

I then read the XML in another application (this below needs cleaned up some, but it works):

```
import xml.dom.minidom

# Parse Config file
f = r'D:\Projects\VIESORE\Code\Python\Vue\Config.xml'
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(f)

image_dir_tag = doc.getElementsByTagName('ProjectDirectory')
if (len(image_dir_tag) == 1):
    working_dir = str(image_dir_tag[0].childNodes[0].toxml())

scene_tag = doc.getElementsByTagName('Scene')
if (len(scene_tag) == 1):
    scene = str(scene_tag[0].childNodes[0].toxml())

# Read some more elements in
```